# How to iterate a nested for loop with a string?

Tags: python, loops, iterator

I need to display rows and columns that look like they are counting from 1 to 5 in the first row, 6 to 10 in the second row, ..., 21 to 25 in the last row.
Here is the code:

```
numberOfRows = 5
for i in range(numberOfRows):
    str1 = ""
    for j in range(numberOfRows):
     # have string square numberOfrows and print them by five
    print(str1)
```

I wonder if having an if statement would be best... I understand i represents the number of rows and j represents the number of columns I would like to know how to get the code to print the desired outcome:

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of printing `i` for each row, you want to fill `str1` (which I imagine is the content of each row), and then print `str1` at the end of the iteration (after the `j` for loop). So something like this

```
numberOfRows = 5
current_number = 1
for i in range (numberOfRows):
    str1 = ""
    for j in range(numberOfRows):
      str1 += str(current_number)
      current_number += 1
    print(str1)
```

also, would definitely recommend getting indentation clear and consistent on your posted code

Comment: I get the following: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'type' and 'int'

Answer (score 1):

You can progress through rows and print columns using an offset calculation based on the row's starting value (which increases by 5 on each row):

```
rows = 5
for r in range(rows): print(*range(r*rows+1,(r+1)*rows+1)))

1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25
```